# Multidimensional array in Java (like in PHP)

Tags: java

In Java I want a multidimensional array (or map) like the one below. Below is an equivalent in PHP. I tried it with hashmap but can't figure out how to handle with multidimensional arrays.

```
[
'item 1' => array(
[0] => array ('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'),
[1] => array ('key3' => 'value3', 'key4' => 'value4'),
),
'item 2' => array(
[0] => array ('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'),
[1] => array ('key3' => 'value3', 'key4' => 'value4'),
)
]
```

I tried the code below. But now, I only have a twodimensional array.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> outerMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();    
innerMap.put("key1", "key2");
innerMap.put("key1", "key2)");
        
outerMap.put("entity", innerMap);
```

Comment: Try to use HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>>

Comment: List - is array for achive item by index and HashMap is key-value collection.

Comment: How many dimension you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below logic

```
        Map<String, List<List<Map<String, String>>>> myMap =  new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("key1","value1");
        map1.put("key2", "value2");

        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("key3","value3");
        map2.put("key4", "value4");

        List<Map<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(map1);
        list1.add(map2);

        Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> mapFinal = new HashMap<>();
        mapFinal.put("item 1", list1);
        mapFinal.put("item 2", list1);

        System.out.println(mapFinal);
```

Output:

```
{
 item 1=[{key1=value1, key2=value2}, {key3=value3, key4=value4}],
 item 2=[{key1=value1, key2=value2}, {key3=value3, key4=value4}]
}
```